# Get HTML input file dialog result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying add an image uploader for my website, and I have already written the uploader method in asp.net mvc. Since I don't want to have two buttons in my page (one for browse and one for upload) I decided to write another function using JQuery to handle it. At this point I've face the problem of having to know the `<input type="file />"` dialog result to run my uploader.

My question is that, is it possible to detect the user's choice (`Open/Cancel`) in JQuery ?

My code looks like this :

```
@using (HTML.BeginForm ("Upload", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="Hidden" />
<input type="submit" id="upload" class="Hidden" />
}

<button id="UploadIt">Image</button>
```

and the java script:

```
$('#UploadIt').click(function() {
    $('#file').trigger("clcik");
    //now if (dialog result is Open) {$('#upload').trigger("click");}
    // else {Do Nothing}

});
```

Comment: use the change() event to fire upon file choice. if input.files.length==0, the user canceled.

Comment: @dandavis: Thank you very much, I'm reading it's documentation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the `change() event` documentation (dandavis mentioned it in the comment), I managed to fix the problem. However I decided to share my solution in case anyone faces the same issue.

```
$('#UploadIt').click(function () {
    $('#file').trigger("click");
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files[0].size > 0) { Upload(); }
        else { }
    });       
});
```